# Why isn't score1 or score 2 incrementing

Tags: java, arraylist

I've been writing practice code for the AP java exam and I made a program that is supposed to simulate a game of war.

I made two methods, one for dealing the cards, and the other for the game.

I made a for loop with an if statement in it to iterate through the ArrayList and compare each element, it awards a point to which every element was higher.

But the issue is at the end, it just returns the scores as zero.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Warr_Card_Game {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Integer> Hand1 = new ArrayList<Integer>(26); //This is player 1's hand
        ArrayList<Integer> Hand2 = new ArrayList<Integer>(26); //This is player 2's hand
        Dealer(Hand1, Hand2);
        System.out.println(Hand1.size() + "\n" + Hand2.size()); // to ensure both hands are the same size

        for(int i= 0; i < Hand1.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(Hand1.get(i) + " " + Hand2.get(i)); // to see live gameplay
        }

        Game(Hand1,Hand2);

        if (Game(Hand1, Hand2) == true ) {
            System.out.println("Player 1 Wins");// to see who won
        }
        else if(Game(Hand1, Hand2) == false) {
            System.out.println("Player 2 Wins");
        }


    }


    /**
     * 
     * @param arr
     * @param arr2
     * acts as a dealer in dealing the cards to each player
     */

    public static void Dealer(ArrayList<Integer> arr, ArrayList<Integer> arr2) { 
        for(int x = 0; x <=  51; x++) {
            int i = (int)(Math.random()*13)+2;
            if(x >= 26) {
                arr.add(i);
            }
            else {
                arr2.add(i);
            }

        }
    }
    /**
     * 
     * @param arr
     * @param arr2
     * @return
     * acts as gameplay to compare each card and award points accordingly
     */
    public static boolean Game(ArrayList<Integer> arr, ArrayList<Integer> arr2) {
        int score1 = 0;
        int score2 = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i >= 26; i++) {
            System.out.println(arr.get(i) + arr2.get(i) + "\t" + score1 + " " + score2);
            if(arr.get(i) > arr2.get(i)) {
                score1+= 1; 
            }
            else if (arr.get(i) < arr2.get(i)) {

                score2 += 1 ;
            }
        }
        return (score1>score2); // returns if score1 is or is not higher than score 2
    }

}
```

Comment: I think `for(int i = 0; i >= 26; i++) {` should be `for(int i = 0; i <= 26; i++) {`.

Comment: "It just returns the scores as zero" - I don't see any place where scores are returned. As `score1` and `score2` are local variables inside of `Game` method, they can't be accessed outside of the method.

Comment: Note: you should follow the Java Naming Conventions: variabele names and method names should be written in camelCase.

Comment: Also, You're already calculating the result of `Game`, just store it in a `boolean` instead of calling it in every if statement. i.e. `boolean result = Game(...);` then `if(result){//P1 wins} else {//P2 wins}`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try changing the loop logic in your `Game` method.

Specifically change:

```
for(int i = 0; i >= 26; i++) {
```

To:

```
for(int i = 0; i <= 25; i++) {
```

The original implementation won't perform any loops because `i` is **not** `>= 26`. In the changed version, it should loop through values `0..25` as expected.

Answer (score 0):

there's a problem with your for-loop, so no scores added...

`for(int i = 0; i >= 26; i++)`

try
`for(int i = 0; i < 26; i++)`